# Switching images with time of day in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add another component to a weather app which will change the background image according to the time of day or night.  This will be the components background, How would I be able to do this in react.js?

Answer (score 1):

I made an array with different images, got the time using getHours() and on componentWillMount, it sets the background image. Hope this example helps:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const date = new Date();
const time = date.getHours();

const backgroundImages = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x300',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x200',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/450x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x450',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/750x300',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/150x850',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x300',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/150x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x200',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/450x150',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/350x450',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/750x300',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/150x850',
]

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image_src: ''
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({image_src:backgroundImages[time] })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.state.image_src} alt=""/>
        <p>{time}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date instance for this kind of functionality.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

The hour gets a value (0-23) according to the local time.

You can then set an interval to your state that runs depending on the delay of transition you want for your background component

```
componentDidMount() {
   var intervalId = setInterval(this.backgroundChange, delay);
   this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
}

backgroundChange () => {
    // return an element depending on newDate().getHours()
}
```